# Python Converting minute number to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time

```
df['minutes'] = [0, 360, 1000, 1439]
```

I have a pandas df with a column called minutes that I would like to convert to datetime.

The desired result would look like the following (or a similar datetime format):

```
df['new_min'] = ["00:00","06:00","16:40","23:59"]
```

This didn't seem to work quite the way I wanted it to.

```
df['new_min']=pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['minutes'], unit='m')
```

Comment: any attempt on your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to convert minutes to an hour what you can do is this:

```
def toHour(minutes):
    return str(timedelta(minutes=minutes%1440))[:-3]
```

Now to do that for every element :

```
df['new_min'] = list(map(lambda x: toHour(int(x)), df['minutes']))
```

**EDIT 1**
If you prefer "01:30" instead of "1:30" you can do

```
def toHour(minutes):
        hour = str(timedelta(minutes=minutes%1440))[:-3]
        return "{0:0>5}".format(hour)
```

Comment: Simpler: `list(map(toHour, df['minutes']))`

Comment: what data type is expected for this method.  I am getting a type error.  Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: It should be an array of strings

Comment: hmm sorry.  Looks like my column is an object.

Comment: Try using pandas apply with the function

Comment: df['new_min'] = df.apply(list(map(toHour, df['minutes']))) gives me same error

Comment: Maybe you needed to cast the string as an int, I changed that in the code